# PHP : Problem with Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, facebook

I'm a php newbie, and I'm creating a Facebook application for my flash game.
In the main page of the application, I want to print the current user friends sorted by score.

I get first user friends using my application with this API function:

```
<?php $friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_getAppUsers();?>
```

$friends is an Array with all user friends ID's, every ID is a bigint.

after that I create another array to store in Friends ID's + Scores:

```
<?php
foreach( $friends as $friend )
{
$fscores["$friend"] = get_user_bestscore($friend);
}
?>
```

get_user_bestscore($friend); Function get the score from my DB.

I sort the array to display friends sorted by score:

```
<?php sort($fscores); ?>
```

In final step to dispaly the $fscores array to show friends names from ID, and Score I use:

```
<?php
foreach( $fscores as $fid => $score )
{
echo '<P>';
echo '<fb:profile-pic uid="'.$fid.'" linked="true" /><br>';
echo '<b># '.$counter++.'</b>';
echo '<b>- <fb:name uid="'.$fid.'" useyou="false"/></b><br>';
echo '<b>Score : '.$score.'</b>';
echo '</P>';
}
?>
```

the $score var display the score stored from DB to array correctly, but $fid (Facebook Friend ID) display ex: 0

I used print_r to know $scores array content i found :
Array ( [0] => 5.87 )

and in the first $friends array I found:
`Array ( [0] => 100000625691889 )`

What I want to get is:
`Array ( [100000625691889 ] => 5.87)`

Any solution please,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. It looks like you have an array that looks like this:

```
100000625691889 => 5.87
```

and you're losing the key. If so, that's because you're using [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), which doesn't preserve array indexes. If you want to preserve array keys, use [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) instead.

**Note:** I don't mean sort by key (unless that's what you want). Sorting by key is done by [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). Let me clarify this with some examples:

```
$arr = array(1234 => 5, 5678 => 3, 3456 => 11);
sort($arr);
print_r($arr);
$arr = array(1234 => 5, 5678 => 3, 3456 => 11);
asort($arr);
print_r($arr);
$arr = array(1234 => 5, 5678 => 3, 3456 => 11);
ksort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Sorting by value (`sort()`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 11
)
```

Sorting by value preserving keys (`asort()`):

```
Array
(
    [5678] => 3
    [1234] => 5
    [3456] => 11
)
```

Sorting by key (`ksort()`):

```
Array
(
    [1234] => 5
    [3456] => 11
    [5678] => 3
)
```

Comment: Sorting Associatavly would be the simplest route :) +1

Comment: Thanks for the help (y), worked great with asort, I have to read more and more about array functions and test.

Answer (score 6):

`sort()` function will remove your keys and auto index.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

> Note: This function assigns new keys
>   to the elements in array. It will
>   remove any existing keys that may have
>   been assigned, rather than just
>   reordering the keys.

you can use [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) to sort the array and preserve keys.

Comment: Why not just use http://www.php.net/asort on it's own...I guess I do not see the need for this custom function at least for this scenario.